# FireFox have two audio when play the mp4 with HTML5

Tags: html, firefox, gwt, html5-video

I am going to add video player to a existing website(written in GWT). 
So I add html5 video(`com.google.gwt.media.client.Video`) tag in the page like

> (<video
>   src="http://ip:8081//a/b/c/102/453/2017-10-23-16-39-30/pp4_blog_demo.mp4" style="width: 500px; height: 300px;" autoplay="" controls=""
>   id="ext-gen221">
>       </video>)

And It works fine in chrome and IE. but when I open in firefox , the video can be played but the video seems have two audios..and if I pause or fast forward the video,one of the audio will not be impacted..it will still play the sound..

can anyone help please?

Comment: I also tried to run the firefox in safemode(disable all the plugins)..same result...